# Xamarin Android Binding : Kotlin extensions methods are not attached with Object after binding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am creating Xamarin.Android Binding library from Kotlin AAR file.

Some of the extension methods are added to Context object in this library.

For Example,

```html
Context.GetServiceType(){
...
}
```

While creating Binding library, i am getting below error in

```
Build Output for Extension methods
```

> Kotlin: Renaming extension parameter
> com/*/blesdk/extension/PermissionExtKt - bleSelfPermissionCheck -
> $this$bleSelfPermissionCheck -> obj
>
> Kotlin: Renaming extension parameter
> com/*/blesdk/extension/PermissionExtKt - hasBLESupport -
> $this$hasBLESupport -> obj

And, this extension methods are not added to Context Object.

Comment: Any help @Bas H?